# I want to restrict the user from adding the duplicate value in 'type' field

Tags: python, django, django-models

class Device(models.Model): # name of the table

```
type = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
price = models.IntegerField()

choices = (
    ('AVAILABLE', 'Item ready to be purchased'),
    ('SOLD', 'Item Sold'),
    ('RESTOCKING', 'Item restocking in few days')
)
status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=choices, default="Sold") # Available, Sold, Restocking
issue = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='No Issue')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update your field
`type = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, unique=True)`